# PictureBox image quality is low

Tags: vb.net, url, picturebox

I was using the following code to enter an image url at `TextBox1` and display it in `PictureBox1`.Everything worked.

But suddenly the displayed image quality is lower than the original link. I've tried `PictureBox1.Load(TextBox1.Text)` and changing `SizeMode` still the same result.

Local images are displayed normally.

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Dim client As WebClient
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        client = New WebClient()

        Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = client.DownloadData(TextBox1.Text)

        Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)

        PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)

     End Sub
    End Class
```

I'm using 
`Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel,
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel`
How can I get the image to display without the quality loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was problem with my internet connection,there is too much packetloss which affects the image quality.
I tested the code with another connection and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the website you are linking to provides a low quality image when [hotlinking](http://altlab.com/hotlinking.html) to it. This is common practice so that users visit the actual site. And it doesn't use so much bandwidth.

If this is the case then there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I do't think so.It's the same result for sites like www.imgur.com

Comment: @chinthaka - can you post a link to one of these images?

Comment: basically any image from any site 

http://i.imgur.com/DSczAGG.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/SJ3enz9.jpg
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYzMDg5ODQ1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc2Nzc5._V1_SX300.jpg

Comment: @chinthaka - those images look fine to me using the code you posted

Comment: orginal-
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYzMDg5ODQ1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc2Nzc5._V1_SX300.jpg

what i get from the code-
http://i.imgur.com/rhqoXhY.jpg


I think something is wrong with my .net framework .Should I try a re-install?

Comment: First image won't load for me in a browser - "Referral denied"